# java3d not working on mac mountain lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-mountain-lion, java-3d

I've been trying for hours now to make java 3d work on my macbook and I can't figure out what's wrong with it...
Here is what I've done:
- I downloaded java3d 1.5 and replaced the original files in /System/Library/Java/Extensions.
- I then installed JOGL following a tutorial in the same (...)/Java/Extensions folder.
- As it still did not work, I decided to try the original version of java3d so I renamed the files.

I'm working on a Mac os x mountain lion with java 1.7.0_07
Here is a result of a java -version:

```
    java version "1.7.0_07"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the content of my Java/extensions folder:

```
    AppleScriptEngine.jar   gluegen-rt.jar          j3dutils.jar.new        libAppleScriptEngine.jnilib libgluegen-rt.jnilib            libnewt.jnilib
    MRJToolkit.jar          j3daudio.jar            jai_codec.jar           libJ3D.jnilib               libjogl_desktop.jnilib          mlibwrapper_jai.jar
    QTJava.zip              j3dcore.jar             jai_core.jar            libJ3DAudio.jnilib          libmlib_jai.jnilib              vecmath.jar
    dns_sd.jar              j3dcore.jar.new         jogl-all.jar            libJ3DUtils.jnilib          libnativewindow_awt.jnilib      vecmath.jar.new
    gluegen-java-src.zip    j3dutils.jar            jogl-java-src.zip       libQTJNative.jnilib         libnativewindow_macosx.jnilib
```

I can compile java 3d codes with javac but here is the result when I try to launch it:

```
    $> java Hello3d
    JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
    AWT not found
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apple/awt/CGraphicsDevice
        at javax.media.j3d.GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.<clinit>        (GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.java:55)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration(SimpleUniverse.java:368)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:348)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:298)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:215)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:177)
        at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:88)
        at Hello3d.<init>(Hello3d.java:13)
        at Hello3d.main(Hello3d.java:27)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.awt.CGraphicsDevice
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 9 more
```

The java class that I'm trying to launch comes from [the official tutorial](http://java3d.org/starting.html).

Do you have any idea how I could fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: At first, installing Java3D or any other Java libraries as an extension or in the JVM is a bad idea. It can cause conflicts when using Java Webstart, applets and other applications. The "official" tutorial you quote is neither official nor up-to-date whereas mine is: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/ Follow Harvey's advise below and it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid that Java3D 1.5 is incompatible with newer versions of OSX, there's nothing
you can do.

I've forked the Java3D code and replaced the native code backends with a JOGL2 backend

You can find information about installing JOGL2 on OSX here (where there is also a Java3d
forum available):
http://jogamp.org/

And you can get prebuilt jar files for my Java3d here (under downloads):

https://github.com/hharrison/

(j3d-core, j3d-utils, vecmath)

Fair warning, this only works with Java6 on OSX currently, I've been trying to debug the
problems with Java7 on OSX, but have no ETA for a solution.....good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Does your fork work exactly as Java3d would? (same names, same potential errors, etc.)?
I'm asking that because I have to do a Java3d project for school and I need to know if I can use your fork or not...
Thanks!

Comment: Correct, there have been zero API changes.  The differences are a few multithreading fixes, some internal memory use reduction and the removal of the native D3D and OpenGL backends.  My fork is a pure-java project and relies on JOGL2 to do the native interop.

Comment: Migrating to JOGL2 is a huge undertaking - it is completely redesigned with profiles and such.  Is there not any way to just recompile the old stuff with "sun.awt." vs "apple.awt" as this is where those components moved?

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to use the latest version of Java3D from github, and I'm still having this problem with Java7 even though I read on a forum that the Java7 issues are fixed (at least when using JCanvas). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: JeffG: there have been _zero_ API changes, the switch to using JOGL2 is completely behind the scenes, you should literally be able to just replace the old java3d jars with mine, and add the jogl2 jars and it should Just Work (tm).

Comment: Harvey is mostly right, our fork works correctly under OS X thanks to JOGL 2 improvements BUT please don't replace old Java 3D if they are located into a directory which is discouraged to use for third party libraries, remove them. Follow my instructions here: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb If you replace badly located JARs, you might cause some conflicts and break some applications.